# how can i display a result from a server javascript function to a html page using angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

This is a form that will go to the javascript page and will upload the photo to the server

```
  <div class="col-sm-5" style="border-right: 1px solid #ccc">
               <div class="subStyle" ng-show="showDiv1">
                   <form id        =  "uploadForm"
                      enctype   =  "multipart/form-data"
                      action    =  "/api/photo"
                      method    =  "post">

                      <input type="file" name="userPhoto" /> 
                      <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
                   </form>
                </div>
                </div>
```

This is the `JavaScript` function

```
 function confirmUploaded() {
  res.end("File was successfully uploaded -- " + outText);

}
```

How would i call this function from the `JavaScript` file to the **HTML** page

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want to call the function when the user's hits submit?

Answer (score 1):

res.end is not a client side, It is a server side code and need to be send from the server end(NodeJS).

Make use of $http.success in angular and then on success attach the result to a particular div or header tags and use css for formatting.